# React state object parsing issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs

There's a flaw in the following logic I can't isolate and understand. I have a React dapp (decentralized app), which has a function that listens to an event on Ethereum blockchain. The function gets the event result and stores it in the component's state:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
  eventData: [
    ...prevState.eventData,
    result[0].args
  ]
}))
```

If `console.log(this.state.eventData)`, I see:

```
[
    [{
            "logIndex": 0,
            "transactionIndex": 0,
            "transactionHash": "0xec912b5811f72b9e821fd62f7c79e45c09c641bb9bf4fff3be9e4997be27cd76",
            "blockHash": "0x84f988d6611ba75e8321e20abf23620d68efb0ff721b85447b8072cd5ff07525",
            "blockNumber": 16,
            "address": "0x985b025b6baa40c6d5c7247f4d608efdfc24b81b",
            "type": "mined",
            "event": "EventOne",
            "args": {
                "paramOne": "0x6a7a88d1f9f6250e1115d05a0489e584d0a0c7c0",
                "paramTwo": "90",
                "paramThree": "2",
                "paramFour": "479",
                "paramFive": "110123595505617976",
                "paramSix": "1",
                "paramSeven": true
            }
        },
        {
            "logIndex": 0,
            "transactionIndex": 0,
            "transactionHash": "0x776ecfd9a1efe0a0d399a4a3d56f2121d5305e4d3219c13ca4e960bcdcce460c",
            "blockHash": "0x109907689e47d96a61bffc0ec4eac5cf4295361d57c9a25fe53aa68e1412eadc",
            "blockNumber": 18,
            "address": "0x985b025b6baa40c6d5c7247f4d608efdfc24b81b",
            "type": "mined",
            "event": "EventOne",
            "args": {
                "paramOne": "0x6a7a88d1f9f6250e1115d05a0489e584d0a0c7c0",
                "paramTwo": "90",
                "paramThree": "17",
                "paramFour": "480",
                "paramFive": "110123595505617976",
                "paramSix": "2",
                "paramSeven": true
            }
        }
    ]
]
```

Then, I need to iterate over the state object and render the results, for which I have the following function. There's a logic that checks for another state, and if the condition hasn't been met, checks for another. Then, it maps the results of `this.state.eventData`:

```
{this.state.eventData
        .filter(
          data =>
            this.state.allRecords|| this.state.account === data.paramOne
        )
        .slice(0, 10)
        .reverse()
        .map(
          (
            {
              paramOne,
              paramTwo,
              paramThree,
              paramFour,
              paramFive,
              paramSix
            },
            i
          ) => (
            <div className="event-result-table-container" key={i}>
              <div className="result-cell">{paramOne}</div>
              <div className="result-cell">
                <span>{paramTwo? "Win" : "Lose"}</span>
              </div>
              <div className="result-cell">{paramThree}</div>
              <div className="result-cell">{paramFour}</div>
              <div className="result-cell">{paramFive/ 10000}</div>
              <div className="result-cell-last">{paramSix}</div>
            </div>
          )
        )}
```

**Expected result:**
I see the rendered blocks with filled-in data from `this.state.eventData`.

**Observed result:**
Fields are empty for some reason.

What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

`paramOne, paramTwo, paramThree...` undefined in map

Try like this

```
.map(
          (
            {args},
            i
          ) => (
            <div className="event-result-table-container" key={i}>
              <div className="result-cell">{args.paramOne}</div>
              <div className="result-cell">
                <span>{args.paramTwo? "Win" : "Lose"}</span>
              </div>
              <div className="result-cell">{args.paramThree}</div>
              <div className="result-cell">{args.paramFour}</div>
              <div className="result-cell">{args.paramFive/ 10000}</div>
              <div className="result-cell-last">{args.paramSix}</div>
            </div>
          )
    )}
```

Comment: I get `Main.js:683 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'paramOne' of undefined`

Comment: In `console.log(this.state.eventData)` result `paramOne, paramTwo, paramThree...` properties are inside args object. How can you access them directly in map and filter function like `this.state.eventData.filter( data =>data.paramOne)`?

Comment: I tried your solution, and get the error with that.

Comment: Try console.log(this.state.eventData) in render function and check final result of it

Comment: Actually that's the thing. I see the object in the console, but when I copy the path of a parameter, I get an undefined error.

Answer (score 0):

You can even specify @aseferov answer to what u wanted to do by second destruction like

```
.map(
      (
        {args: {
          paramOne,
          paramTwo,
          paramThree,
          paramFour,
          paramFive
        }},
        i
      ) => (
        <div className="event-result-table-container" key={i}>
          <div className="result-cell">{args.paramOne}</div>
          <div className="result-cell">
            <span>{args.paramTwo? "Win" : "Lose"}</span>
          </div>
          <div className="result-cell">{args.paramThree}</div>
          <div className="result-cell">{args.paramFour}</div>
          <div className="result-cell">{args.paramFive/ 10000}</div>
          <div className="result-cell-last">{args.paramSix}</div>
        </div>
      )
)}
```

You can see it [here](https://codeburst.io/es6-destructuring-the-complete-guide-7f842d08b98f), if you want a better understanding of the subject.

Comment: Thanks, but you've got lots of errors in your code.